# Checking if .txt file is loaded

Tags: python, file, loading

My program has got a menu with different options.
if you select `l` or `L` it will load the packages.txt file. That works fine.

```
    if option.upper() == 'L':
        f = open( "packages.txt", "r" )
```

Then if you select `d` or `D` (d for display) it should check if the file is loaded and then display("print") the information given in the file.

```
if option.upper() == 'D':
    if open( "packages.txt", "r" ):
        a = []
        for line in f:
            a.append(line)
            print(line)

    if open( "packages.txt", "r" ):
        print("fail")
```

That is the code i wrote, the printing and displaying works fine, but I cant get my head around the if file open statement.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is you are opening the file again, rather than checking the existing file:

```
f = None

...

if option.upper() == 'L':
    f = open( "packages.txt", "r" )
elif opetion.upper() == 'D':
    if f and not f.closed:
        ...
    else:
        print("File not opened.")
```

Note that this is generally a bad idea. It's a much better idea to only open the file when you need it.

So, the better option is something like this:

```
selected = option.upper()
filename = None

if selected == "L":
    filename = "packages.txt"
elif selected = "D":
    if filename:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            ...
    else:
        print("The file to display has not been selected.")
```

Note my use of [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), which is more readable and ensures the file is closed properly, even if you have an exception.

Comment: This is indeed a better design.